# Adding observer after poster NSNotificationCenter workaround?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, delegation

Is it possible to assign a delegate or NSNotificationCenter observer to VC2 that is loaded after VC1, where post takes place?

I have a tabbar app with multiple VCs.  VC 1 is loaded first and the action to trigger a post takes place before VC2 is loaded. In VC2, I need to copy or get reference of an array from VC1.

Is there any other way to do this?  Please help! I've been at this for 4 hours now.  Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that vc2 add itself as an observer to a notification which is already posted ? When does the notification post ? When does vc2 add itself as an observer ?

Comment: Yes!  VC 1 gets loaded first, then didSelect inside of VC is called.  THEN VC2 loads and add itself as an observer; basically the post is done inside of the didSelect method of VC1.

Comment: Why not add VC2 as an observer in its init method ? `viewDidLoad` method is only called when the view property of `UIViewController` is accessed at first time.

Comment: Actually, I found a work around solution to my original problem which is much simpler.  Only took about 4hrs :(  Appreciate the help, just the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it may help you.

**FirstViewController**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSArray *temp=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"postArrayObject" object:temp];

}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objFirstViewController:) name:nil object:nil];

}
-(void)objFirstViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name]isEqualToString:@"postArrayObject"])
    {
        NSArray *cellData = [notification object];
        if (cellData)
        {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WORKING"
                                                              message:nil
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [message show];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: OH! Interesting.  I didn't even think about the life cycle methods! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is better if you create a sort of NavigationController that has a reference to all VCs and then switch them with `addSubview` and `removeFromSuperview`